# How to scroll Facebook page plugin from javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm developing simple site, I have facebook page plugin, like this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

(call to function 'facebook-jssdk' exists).

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <!-- note 500px is max width of fb plugin-->
    <div class="fb-page" style="height: 1000px; width: 500px;" data-href=""
     data-tabs="timeline" data-send="false" data-height="1000" data-width="500"
     data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true"
     data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" id="my-fb-page"></div>
```

I want to scroll the content inside plugin up and down **in code** once loaded, 
how do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to scroll the content inside plugin up and down in code once loaded, how do I do that?

You don’t. – Because this renders as an iframe that loads its content from a different domain, so the *Same Origin Policy* denies any JavaScript access to it from your site.

---

What you want would only be possible if Facebook explicitly offered an API for this, but they don’t